# CP-SAT ortools - Is there any complete list of possible/available StringParameters for the CpSolver?

Tags: solver, constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

I wonder if there is any list of string parameters documented.

So far, I only know `max_time_in_seconds` and `num_search_workers`.

Screening code files as e.g. https://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/CpSolver_8cs_source.html didn't provide further intel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As many things in Google, OR-Tools uses [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) to serialize data.

Here's a list of all `.proto` files in OR-Tools: https://github.com/google/or-tools/search?l=Protocol+Buffer

The parameters for the CP-SAT solver are listed in the `sat_parameters.proto` file:

- https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto